# ngModel is not displaying the value

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular2-template

In Html it is not showing `ngModel` where selectedValueModel is already assigned. 
Tried with `[ngValue]` also and it is giving `undefined` to my `ngModelChange` function.

Thanks in Advance.

```
foods: Food[] = [
    {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'},
    {value: 'pizza-1', viewValue: 'Pizza'},
    {value: 'tacos-2', viewValue: 'Tacos'}
  ];
selectedValueModel = {value: 'steak-0', viewValue: 'Steak'};
@Output() selectedValueChange = new EventEmitter()

changing(newValue: any) {
    this.selectedValueModel = newValue
    this.selectedValueChange.emit(newValue)
  }
```

### My HTML:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" 
   [(ngModel)]="selectedValueModel.value" 
   (ngModelChange)="changing($event)" name="food">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
        {{food.viewValue}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: do you get any error message in the console?

Comment: What do you want to do? To set preselected value or to take selected value?

Comment: I would like to do both in the sense, i'm assinging an object to 'selectedValueModel' which is binded to ngModel, When i enter into the page it should display that(preselected or preassigned) and it is displaying. And my query here is if i select anything, (ngModelChange is triggering and it is sending the selected value to the function.But not the whole object only Value. Finally I need selected whole object.

Answer (score 3):

For those who might hit here having issue with their `ngModel` not displaying the value of their model, there might be another input with the same `name` in your form. i.e.

```
<form>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedValueModel.value" name="food">
    <input [(ngModel)]="anotherModel" name="food">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change :

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedValueModel.value"
(ngModelChange)="changing($event)" name="food">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
    {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

to:

```
<mat-form-field>
<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" 
[(ngModel)]="selectedValueModel"
(ngModelChange)="changing($event)" name="food">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
    {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Comment: Please consider explaining the difference between the OP's code and your code, as well as what exactly you have done instead of answering with a code-only answer.

Comment: I'm assinging an object to 'selectedValueModel' which is binded to ngModel, When i enter into the page it should display that(preselected or preassigned) and it is displaying. And my query here is if i select anything, (ngModelChange is triggering and it is sending the selected value to the defined function, But not the whole object only Value. Finally I need selected whole object.

Answer (score 0):

For capturing whole object in Angular material, in contrary to pure angular, you use `[value]` to bind the whole object, instead of `[ngValue]`.

Also, now that we are binding a whole object, instead of a primitive we need to compare your predefined object with the object in the array, so we can use `compareWith` that is provided by Angular. So change your code to:

```html
<mat-select placeholder="Favorite food" [(ngModel)]="selectedValueModel" 
  (ngModelChange)="changing($event)" name="food" [compareWith]="compFn">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food"> <!-- Add food as value! -->
    {{food.viewValue}}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

And then the compareWith:

```ts
compFn(c1: Food, c2: Food): boolean {
  return c1 && c2 ? c1.value === c2.value : c1 === c2;
}
```

Here's a **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-thx8xu?file=app/form-field-overview-example.ts)**!